# Example of software evolution or maintenance in a company

Tags: software-update

I'm looking for an example of **software evolution or maintenance** in a company for an **university** assignment. For example, using a new technology.
Can you tell me some ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If your question is solely theory and you don't need an actual example, then:

Modern IT companies are adopting the use of Machine-Learning, or 'A.I' in order to better gather information about customers, altering their products to better meet user requirements and to tailor their designs to each customer.